# Javascript - SyntaxError: Illegal return statement How to fix?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I can't understand where did I made a mistake, but I'm getting the following errors in the code below :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
SyntaxError: return not in function
```

Code:

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
    return Math.floor(bmi);
}
var bmi = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    return 'Your BMI is ' + bmi + ' so you are underweight';
}
if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    return 'Your BMI is ' + bmi + ' so you have a normal weight';
} else {
    return 'Your BMI is ' + bmi + ' so you are overweight';
}
```

I'm a total newbie so i appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Your last 3 returns aren't in a function, as the error says. Where are you wanting to return that data to? Did you mean to use `console.log`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function with the return parameter. First apply math.floor (bmi) under a new variable name. then return this variable. Like This:

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
var bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
var newBmi = Math.floor(bmi);
return newBmi;
```

Comment: This is plain wrong. The OP's `bmiCalculator` function is fine.